# ねん in the Kansai dialect

Tags: dialects, kansai-ben

I've heard the ねん ending a lot in 関西弁{かんさいべん} but I'm still struggling to find when it's used. Can you use it with all kinds and conjugations of verbs? I've heard ちゃうねん over and over, but if I try to use ねん with e.g. 食べる I can't make it sound right in my head. And what is the standard Japanese equivalent of やねん？ だよ？　If it is, then what's the difference between やで and やねん？

Comment: That で as in やで is a version of ぜ.(or vice versa)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Can you use it with all kinds and conjugations of verbs?

Yes, I think so.

(verb+ねん/で)
ちゃうねん ≒ ちがうんだ(よ)/ちがうの(よ)
ちゃうで ≒ ちがうよ

行くねん ≒ 行くんだ(よ)/行くの(よ)
行くで ≒ 行くよ

食べんねん ≒ 食べるんだ(よ)/食べるの(よ)
食べんで ≒ 食べるよ

(negative)
知らんねん ≒ 知らないんだ(よ)/知らないの(よ)
知らんで ≒ 知らないよ

食べへんねん ≒ 食べないんだ(よ)/食べないの(よ)
食べへんで ≒ 食べないよ

(i-adjective+ねん/で)
かわいいねん ≒ かわいいんだ(よ)/かわいいの(よ)
かわいいで ≒ かわいいよ

(noun+や/na-adjective+ねん/で)
せやねん/そやねん ≒ そうなんだ(よ)/そうなの(よ)
せやで/そやで ≒ そうだよ/そうよ

あほやねん ≒ 馬鹿なんだ(よ)/馬鹿なの(よ)
あほやで ≒ 馬鹿だよ/馬鹿よ

Comment: 「なんだよ/なのよ」と「だよ/よ」の違いは何？って聞かれると、困るけど・・・

Comment: 「よ」は「のだ」体の文に意味もなくつく時がありますよね。

Comment: 「なんだよ・なのよ」の「よ」って、オプショナルかも。かっこに入れてみよう・・・