# What is the non-slurred version for 叫んどんねん? 叫んでおらない?

Tags: colloquial-language, manga, dialects, kansai-ben

I have trouble understanding 叫んどんねん in this panel. I thought it must be 叫んでおらない but I don't think it makes sense in this context.

[image: pee]

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/19799/%e3%81%ad%e3%82%93-in-the-kansai-dialect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The talker is saying "トイレの個室で何叫んでるんだよ" (Roughly means *What the hell are you yelling about in the bathroom stall?*) in [Kansai dialect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kansai_dialect), not slur.

It can be divided like:

- トイレ | の | 個室 | で | 何 | 叫んどん | ねん
- トイレ | の | 個室 | で | 何 | 叫んでるん | だよ

Answer (score 10):

叫んどんねん is short for 叫んどるねん, which is short for **叫んでおるねん**, which is 叫んでいるんだ(よ) said in Osaka-ben. There is no negation.

1. おる is used instead of いる in many western dialects to denote progressive aspect. See: [おる in honorific contexts](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/26091/5010) and [Existence verbs in the Kansai Dialect](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/61178/5010)
2. ておる/でおる very commonly contracts to とる/どる. See [this chart](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/18159/5010).
3. `/r/ + vowel` before `/n/` can contract to ん (also in Tokyo colloquial speech). See: [Why is the て-form being used before ん？](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/61958/5010)

ねん is a Osaka-ben specific sentence-final particle which can replace んだ(よ)/のだ(よ).